# How to properly catch exception, not in debug

Tags: python, exception

I wrote a program that can be executed with `-d, --debug`. When running in production, I don't want to confuse the user with the traceback. For now, I have a separate path that does a global `try..catch` statement if executed without debug:

```
@click.command()
@click.option('-d', '--debug', help='Debug mode', is_flag=True)
def cli(debug, **kwargs):
    runner = Runner(**kwargs)
    if not debug:
        try:
           failures = runner.run()
        except Foo as e:
           handleFooException(e)
           exit(1)
        except Bar as e: 
           handleBarException(e)
           exit(1)
        except e:
           if hasattr(e, 'msg'):
              click.secho(f'Error: {e.msg})
              exit(1)
    else: 
        failures = runner.run()
    click.echo('')
    return failures


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

This has several drawbacks:

- `__main__.py` has to know how to handle all types of exceptions in the whole program
- This is cumbersome

Is there any alternative, better approach to handle exceptions in production environment?

Comment: In a production environment you'd ideally send the traceback to a logging service to help you debug.  If you don't have a logging service, just not doing anything and allowing the traceback to print is actually the best thing IMO, because then the user can send it to you; if the traceback just gets eaten, you might never be able to fix the problem.

Comment: What is it you're doing in handleFooException? Seems strange that there is something specific to FooExceptions that you cannot do further up the call stack.

Comment: Please explain: "`__main__.py` has to know how to handle all types of exceptions in the whole program". Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: The users are student that are not familiar with programming. When exception occurs, they cannot figure out how to deal with the traceback. Getting the last exception message isn't always understandable. So my goal would be to register a global exception handler that can format the exception to be understandable by many.

Comment: Are you asking how to use the exception handler, or how to write it?  Using it is easy: catch `Exception` in a single `except`, pass it to the handler, let the handler inspect the exception and handle it according to its type.  Writing a handler that can take any arbitrary exception and make it so a non-technical user can solve the problem on their own is the hard part!

Comment: The better approach is to treat top-level uncaught exceptions as programming errors on your part, and focus on making sure those messages get to you to be fixed, rather than relying on the user to fix them.  Usually exceptions need to be caught closer to the point of origin if you want to actually recover from them in a useful way.